# nginx rewrite Issue, why does it just replaces one matched string?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I want to replace my url via Nginx's rewrite directive. For instance, the client side requests http://127.0.0.1/user/user_id/, and I want to let Nginx *rewrite* the url to http://127.0.0.1/person/person_id/.

My Nginx configuration is like this:
`rewrite (.*)user(.*) $1person$2;`

But I fount the Nginx changes the url to **.../user/person_id/**

Could someone tell me how to change the `user` to `person` via rewrite directive?

Comment: Show full server config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the first instances of `user` and `person`are constant and that there is always a slash after the second item, you can try:

```
rewrite ^/user/user_([^/]+)/(.*)$ /person/person_$1/$2 ;
```

Comment: That can cover my most cases, but there still some url patterns can't. I finally change my url configuration directly in the code of my App. Anyway, thanks @Dayo

Comment: If you add the problem url patterns, they can be looked into ... although I note you have a work around.

Answer (score 0):

well this single case you are talking about can be solved simple:

```
rewrite ^/user/user_id/(.*)$ /person/person_id/$1 ;
```

Comment: No, this is just one url pattern, there are other url patterns like /user/user_activity/ ,   /user/get_user_.../